# Intellij - Import Database Schema - refresh stuck on "Trigger sources"

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, schema

Im using Intellin Idea 2016.3.3 Ultimate and MySql database 5.6.25.

Trying to refresh schema causes Intellij to stuck at [introspecting schema, trigger sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpSrJ.png).

Could someone point probable cause?

Comment: any updates? I have the same problem!

Comment: Unfortunately no, problem still persist. Can you remember what did you change, when the problem started?

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember when this problem starts. Finally, I found this project to generate java class from mysql: https://github.com/tianshuang/mysql_table_toJavaBean, hope it helps!